# What are the key differences between jogging the robot in world mode and joint mode for both ABB and Fanuc robots?

Tags: automation, robotics

ROBOTIC MOVEMENT

Jogging of robots

What are the key differences between jogging the robot in world mode and joint mode for both ABB and Fanuc robots?

Comment: Robot Framework is a test automation tool and has nothing to do with moving robot arms. You might want to remove the tag.

Comment: Maybe the Robotics Community is a better place to ask: https://robotics.stackexchange.com/